# Unable to create OpenJPAEntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, osgi, openjpa, osgi-bundle

I have created the OSGI bundle project with JPA 2.0 support. I am using OpenJpa as a JPA provider. when I run the bundle, I Could not create OpenJPAEntityManagerFactory. Please fine the code which I used to create OpenJPAEntityManagerFactory.

```
OpenJPAEntityManagerFactory emf = OpenJPAPersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
                        "StudentServiceProvider",
                        "META-INF/persistence.xml");
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="StudentServiceProvider">

        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <class>com.student.serviceprovider.model.Student</class>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/NYL" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="root" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="root" />
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Tool=INFO" />
            <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported" />
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Tool=INFO" />

            <!-- To avoid foreign key issues -->
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SchemaFactory" value="native(ForeignKeys=true)" />

            <!-- Auto create tables -->
            <property name="jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

In src folder I have META-INF and i created the persistence.xml with in that(META-INF/persistennce.xml).

Please let me know to resolve this issue.

Comment: Still, I am having the same issue. I created the JPA project(not bundle) with OPenJpa and it is working fine with the same configuration. When I create the bundle I am facing this issue. Please anybode help me to identify the issue

Answer (score 0):

It'd probably be helpful if you listed what the error is you are getting, but it might be because you have this line twice:

```
<property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Tool=INFO" />
```

This is just a stab in the dark since you don't mention what the error is and I just happen to be getting an error message of "Equivalent property keys "openjpa.Log" and "Log" are specified in configuration." for something I'm working on.